# Another version of correspondence theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, set-theory, quotient-group

Let $X,Y$ be a sets and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. $X/\sim$ is the quotient set or partition by $\sim$. Let us consider the sets $\{\tilde f:X/\sim\to Y\}$ and $\{f:X\to Y:f$ has the property $*\}$, where $*$ is the property that $[x]=[y]\implies f(x)=f(y)$. Then we can see that there exists a bijection between these two sets. Using this bijection, for two groups $G$ and $G'$ and for a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, we can define a bijection between $\{f:G\to G':f $is a homomorphism and $ H\subset \ker(f)\}$ and $\{\tilde f:G/H\to G': \tilde f$ is a homomorphism$\}$, I want to know is this another version of correspondence theorem?I also want to know what are the applications of this result. Can someone help me?

Comment: I assume you meant $\{\overline{f}:X/\sim\to Y\}$?

Comment: The first theorem does not imply the second as you seem to claim. It gives you a bijection between *set maps* from $G$ to $G'$ that agree on cosets with *set maps* from $G/H$ to $G'$. You would now need to establish that this set map correspondence restricts to a *homomorphism* correspondence: thatis, that if the set map on $G$ is a morphism, then the corresponding set map on $G/H$ is a morphism, and vice-versa. You have not done so, hence you do not have a proof yet.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No I have done that,but did not mention it here.

Comment: I guess I was supposed to read your mind to realize that, given that you did not mention it... In any case, that is a key part of the argument and the meat of the theorem in question. I would say you have not provided a new proof, you've just hidden the actual proof elsewhere and failed to mention it. It's not "another version" of the theorem, it *is* the theorem.